# interpret TF-IDF scores from sklearn TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I am struggling with figuring how to interpret and reconcile the TF-IDF scores from sklearn TfidfVectorizer.
To illustrate I have a very simple example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import 
TfidfVectorizer
data = ['dog is sitting on bed', 'cat is 
sitting on sofa', 'where is that dog']

vector = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf = vector.fit_transform(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(tfidf.toarray(), columns = 
vector.get_feature_names())
df
```

The result is:
[print(df)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEysh.png)

If I calculate the TF-IDF of let's say 'dog' manually in the first sentence, I would calculate TF 1/5 = 0.2 because 'dog' is one of 5 words.  Then I would calculate IDF of 'dog': it appears in 2 out of 3 sentences log(3/2) = 0.176.
I then multiply 0.2 * 0.176 =  0.0352.
My question is how is that 0.433067 number for 'dog' in first row calculated?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of `tf-idf` is different from the `sklearn` implementation.

Per the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html), three things lead to you getting a different result:

1. The term frequency is calculated as the raw count of the term in the given document
2. Smoothing is applied to the IDF value
3. Normalisation is performed

To revisit your example, let us first modify the `TfidfVectorizer` in this way:

```
vector = TfidfVectorizer(norm=None)
```

After performing `fit_transform`, we get this output:

```
        bed       cat       dog   is        on   sitting      sofa      that     where
0  1.693147  0.000000  1.287682  1.0  1.287682  1.287682  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
1  0.000000  1.693147  0.000000  1.0  1.287682  1.287682  1.693147  0.000000  0.000000
2  0.000000  0.000000  1.287682  1.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  1.693147  1.693147
```

For the first sentence and the word `dog`, the term frequency is 1, since the word appears once. The IDF is not equal to `log(3/2)`, but rather `log(4/3)`; 1 is added to both the numerator and denominator to prevent divisions by 0 (this behaviour can be disabled by passing `smooth_idf=False`).

`1 + log(4/3)` is approximately equal to  `1.287682`, as expected.

If we then perform L2 normalisation:

```
df.iloc[0] / ((df.iloc[0] ** 2).sum() ** 0.5)
```

We see that we get the same output as the original:

```
bed        0.569431
cat        0.000000
dog        0.433067
is         0.336315
on         0.433067
sitting    0.433067
sofa       0.000000
that       0.000000
where      0.000000
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```